# Need Logon screen for entering domain Logins

Tags: greeter

Succeeded in joining Elementary OS installation to our Windows domain via active directory.  Used winbind, Samba, etc.

Problem:  The login screen only allows for the initially defined user (defined during installation), or a guest session.  How would one go about entering the domain login?

Comment: Same issue to my case, successfully added to the domain. But can't find the domain login in the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and put the following in it:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Then, press `CTRL+ALT+F1` to open the command line and execute `service lightdm restart`.

After that, you should have the option 'Manual login'  at the bottom of the login screen.